# mat-select for date (day-month-year) selection?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to implement a date field using 3 `mat-select` components. How should I fill the day, month (by number) and year fields? I think I should use a constant values on a `ts` file and use these values instead of keeping them in a database table. Am I wrong? And is there a proper example for this kind of usage?

Note: For some limitation I need to use `mat-select` instead of `mat-datepicker`. For this reason please give your suggestions based on `mat-select` approach.

Comment: Have you seen the answer? Did it work?

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar Sorry for late answer, I was trying to convert them to a form control. But as I mentioned in my last comments, I have not :( Any help pls?

Comment: I also voted up and marked it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your limitations, I've created one reusable component for you at 
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-wjrfbb?file=src/app/date-select/date-select.module.ts).

Using this control you can do two-way data (Date) binding.

And you can customize it with your own design choice.

Use of the component is also demonstrated.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried to convert this nice approach as a custom form control, but have not managed to work properly. So, could you pls give another example to convert these 3 selectlist? Any stackblitz example please?

Comment: I followed this approach to create a form component from your example: https://medium.com/@kevinmerckx/creating-a-custom-angular-form-control-43dfc4b654c0

Comment: There is not a completed job actually and I need your helps. Did you read my last comments?

Comment: Ok. We'll see that.

Comment: What will we see?

Comment: Done. Check at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-wjrfbb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Just a little issue: What if I want to add an "Unknown" checkbox for this date component? I think I should not include it to this custom control and use it separately. Or should I add it to this custom form control?

Comment: `"Unknown" checkbox`. What is your purpose?

Comment: **1.** Set the date field as "Unknown" (I already keep date field as string). I think I should use a separate checkbox instead of integrating it to that form control that we created. Am I wrong?

Comment: **2.** Another issue with this approach is making day field optional and others mandatory. I have no idea about how should I pass the field parameters (day, month or year) to this user form control. Any suggestion regarding to that?

Comment: 1. You can add that to the control. But don't integrate with form-control part.

Comment: 2. You can add the day, month, and year as inputs. Then working with form-control get really difficult. After using day, month, and year as input parameters you can make the day field optional. But there will be more difficult to do that. You have to do more research to do these tasks in an efficient way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for #1. Regarding to #2, I think I should pass the mandatory field or just a boolean value if the day field is mandatory. Because there will not be another option to make month or year I think. Then pass this `idDayRequired` parameter as input to that user form control and make necessary operation in it according to the value. Is that sounds good?

Comment: You're welcome. And you should not use too many fields. So, try to handle it with just the 4 (day, month, year, Date) field.

Comment: By the way, how to make mat-select first option null? I tried to add null as first element of the date arrays, but not worked properly. Any idea? You may post your answer to [How to make mat-select first option null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846927/how-to-make-mat-select-first-option-null/66847602#66847602).

Comment: On the other hand, as the Day field is optional, how can I change this custom form control to emit `string` instead of `Date`? Unfortunately, I have not managed to convert it properly. Could you post it as a second Stackblitz (the first one will be useful also, you can keep it). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `Date` data type causing some problems as the Day field is not mandatory. So, may it be better to change the data type while emitting? I tried to pass string by concatenating day-month-year values but not works properly. Any idea?

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar how can i bind date from api response and allow user to modify the date like am getting value as `{ purchaseDate: '22/09/2022/ }` ?

Comment: @Flavio, Example:
`<date-select [(Date)]="apiResponse.purchaseDate"></date-select>`