# How to make mat-select first option null?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I use 3 `mat-select` for day-month-year selection as shown on this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-wjrfbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-select%2Fdate-select.component.ts).

I need to make the first options as null or undefined and modify that code as shown below:

```
allDates: number[] = [null];
dates: number[] = [null];
months: number[] = [null];
years: number[] = [null];
```

But I am not sure if it is a good idea or is there a proper way for `mat-select`. I also try to set `[value]=null` for the `mat-select` options, but in that case it does not receive the value properly. So, what is a proper way for this?

Comment: didn't understand your purpose. You want to disable fields or let the users select empty option.

Comment: I just want to let user to select empty day, month or year.

Comment: E.g: If the user selects empty day, then what is the output of the control?

Comment: I convert the output as string by concanating Day + '.' + Month + '.' + FullYear. Any idea or suggestion regarding to that?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason they need to be null? In my opinion it is more confusing to have a blank option.

Play around with the stack blitz to see how it behaves when initialized as an empty array vs when it is bound to an array with one null item. I think the UX is great when the mat-select is bound to an empty array. The mat-label resides in the select box, easy to see what type of data is in the select. Also when you click it, it doesn't show any options, because there aren't any. If you have a null, then the dropdown opens with one blank item.

I don't think there is anything wrong with the code you provided.

Edit:

You can bind the mat-select item with an object and use a display property to show the text and a value property to bind to the actual value.

Say you have an interface like this:

```
export interface DateSelectItem
{
    value: number;
    label: string;
}

let dates: DateSelectItem[] = [
    {
        value: -1
        label: "None"
    }
];

selectedDate: DateSelectItem;
```

in the template:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedDate">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let date of dates" [value]="date">
      {{date.label}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can use just strings and convert them back and forth with their number equivalents.

Or if you use an object you can use the label property to display something other than the value.

EDIT: Modified StackBlitz

You will probably need to update the business logic on what you want the resulting date to look like if the user selects 'None' for day-of-the-month.

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-hnfvyd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I want to let user to be able to not select any option. So, how can I do this?

Comment: I would maybe use a mat-slide-toggle with a label that says something like: "Would you like to select a date?" with the on/off switch to hide the mat-selects if they don't want to pick a date. Or you could just initialize the arrays like this: `dates: string[] = ["None"];`

Comment: It may also be possible, but I would prefer to let the user to select or unselect the Day select list. So, maybe it is good idea to emit this form control as string instead of Date. Any idea?

Comment: You can use an object.

Comment: Any example pls by modifying the [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-wjrfbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-select%2Fdate-select.component.ts)?